# Functions of time

Tags: kinematics

Following are the functions of time:
$s(t)$ = distance a particle travels from time $0$ to $t$
$v(t)$ = velocity of a particle at time $t$
$a(t)$ = acceleration of a particle at time $t$.

If we want to see how the position of a particle changes with respect to time only, then its velocity must remain constant with time. Likewise, if we want to see how velocity varies with time, then the distance between the former position of the particle and the current position should remain constant with time. Similarly, if we want to see how acceleration varies with time, then the difference between the initial velocity $U$ and final velocity $V$ should remain constant with time. Is this what the above functions of time tell us?

Comment: Hi Samama. You've grouped your question under http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62099/11062. Then, what's the importance of this?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy He did the same , asking these questions on Math.SE twice like he did here.

Comment: I couldn't remove it...!